# Using Max with Date Values with or without the Nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Now, after so many hours trying to figure this out, i really now need help.

I have a table which contains millions of records of about 50,000 customers. Each customer has at least 2000 transactions.

I want to have a table that holds the latest date each customer had either bought or sold something on the website.

I have tried

```
'FOR PURCHASES
Update tblmycustomers
set LastBoughtdate = (Select ISNULL(Max(trndate), '01-Jan-1900') from tbltransactions where Type = 'PURCHASES')
from tbltransactions.AccountRef = tblmycustomers.AccountNo
```

It works fine for records that have "PURCHASES" but for those who dont have PURCHASES, it saves another date which is wrong

I want it to return the default date ("01-Jan-1900") for every customer who doesn't have purchases and return the Maximum transaction date for those who has.

Please help me.

Comment: your first problem is using an update statement in your use case. Tested using a select query the results will be the same but without the theory headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE c
SET LastBoughtdate = ISNULL(Q.MaxBoughtDate, '1900-01-01')
FROM tblmycustomers c
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT AccountRef, MAX(trndate) AS MaxBoughtDate
    FROM tblTransactions
    WHERE Type = 'PURCHASES'
    GROUP BY AccountRef) Q ON Q.AccountRef = AccountNo
```

Comment: Heavens Gate ! Perfect ! Gave me exactly what i has spent almost a day working at.
Thanks a lot ! You made my day hands down.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would work. The driver table being "customers", you want to left join to the transactions...so you get all customer records even if there is no transactions. So...do something like this :)

```
    Select cust.AccountNo
    ,      isnull(max(trans.trndate), convert(date,'01/01/1900')) as LastBoughtDate
    from tblmycustomers as cust
    left join tbltransactions as trans on cust.AccountNo = trans.AccountRef
    where type = 'PURCHASES' 
    group by cust.AccountNo
```

Comment: this will skip to update all the accounts without any purchases. If you specify 'where type = purchase' then 'left join' is the same as 'inner join'.

Comment: good point....I have an edit, but I like your answer....was pretty much what I had intended :)

Answer (score 1):

This updates based on a max transdate of an left outer joined subquery of the account number.

```
UPDATE 
    T
SET 
    T.LastBoughtdate=COALESCE(A.LastPurchaseDate,'01/01/1900')
FROM
    tblmycustomers T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        T2.AccountRef
        LastPurchaseDate=MAX(trndate)
    FROM
        tbltransactions T2
    WHERE
        T2.Type='PURCHASES'
    GROUP BY
        T2.AccountRef
)AS A ON A.AccountRef=T.AccountNo
```

Comment: this will skip to update all the accounts without any purchases as subquery contains only rows with purchases

Comment: a new edition misses ISNULL() on top. Otherwise LastBoughtDate will be NULL for all the accounts without purchases. So finally it will be almost same code as in my answer :)  COALESCE is probably not required as trndate probably can't be NULL. It's a bug if transaction date of transaction is null.

Comment: I had an INNER JOIN which would not have worked after hacking out the query. However, after I fixed it up, I still don't get you part about the "misses ISNULL() on top". The crux of the matter was that the "LastUpdated" should be min date or something if null, otherwise the value. Is that not what is does?

Comment: No, your subquery returns only the accounts with at least one purchase. So if a customer don't have any purchases, A.LastPurchaseDate will be NULL. It is required to set the date to default date 1900-01-01 if a customer don't have purchases, so you need to add ISNULL(...)

Comment: COALESCE(NULL,'01-Jan-1900') Returns -->'01-Jan-1900'

Comment: yes, but just for purchases as you use (WHERE T2.Type='PURCHASES')

Comment: Updated same as yours

Answer (score 0):

If your "LastBoughtdate" is DateTime. I think you need to convert the "01-01-1900'. Convert(Date, '01-01-1900', 101).